# User Accounts Privileges

Tags: windows-7, windows

Under Windows 7, is there a user account group or type which restricts software installation and changing of system configuration?
Or do I have to manually manipulate the configurations in the Local Group Policy to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Regular user accounts (non-administrators) are restricted from installing software and changing most system configurations in Windows. You shouldn't have to change the LGP unless you want something specific. Like a user that can't use USB devices, but can install software, et al. Hierarchy is guests < users < administrators, from least to most respectively.

Comment: Ever sense Vista, you don't need admin to install stuff that doesn't require UAC. Which, trust me, is quite a bit of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[I believe that the standard Account type answers your question](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/what-is-a-standard-user-account).